# Scale the spatial variables of two adjacent regions with different scalings?

Tags: coordinate-systems, dimensional-analysis

A system consists of two adjacent regions in the coordinate system $(r,z)$, as shown in the following figure. [image]

Region $\color{red}{\rm{B}}$ is the top domain of a small circle cut by the horizontal axis $r$. Note that region $\color{red}{\rm{B}}$ is not a half circle, whose center locates in the negative half $z$-axis. Region $\color{blue}{\rm{A}}$ is the top half of the bigger $\color{blue}{\rm{circle}}$, whose center are $O (0,0)$, minus the region $\color{red}{\rm{B}}$ (smaller circle cap).

To render the governing equations in the two domains dimensionless, I want to introduce separate set of scales for spatial variables in the two regions. For example, in the region $\color{red}{\rm{B}}$,

$$R=\frac{r}{2}, \quad Z=\frac{z}{0.2},$$
which means the $r$-coordinate is shrunk by half, and $z$-coordinate is stretched by 5 times. While in the region $\color{blue}{\rm{A}}$ both coordinates are enlarged by five times.
$$(R,Z)=\frac{(r,z)}{0.2}.$$

In my system, there are boundary conditions applied on the $\color{red}{\rm{arc}}$ of the small circle $\color{red}{\rm{B}}$.
My question is: with abovementioned geometric feature, whether or not I can using different scalings for spatial variables in the two adjacent regions?

Thanks for your help. Any comments are welcome.

Comment: Do you have any specific demands on the coordinates? Are there allowed to be different points who have the same coordinates? Does there need to be a smooth transition along the border between B and A?

Comment: @mathreadler, Thanks, I want to transform the spatial variables for region A firstly, while the outer region is infinite previously, a finite region B is then chosen and scaled. There are not allowed to be different points having the same coordinate in the regions A and B themselves. I want the boundary between B and A to be scaled according to the scaling for B, because I expect it belongs to B.